# Merge lists with stream API

Tags: java, list, java-8, java-stream

I have the following situation

```
Map<Key, ListContainer> map; 

public class ListContainer {
  List<AClass> lst;
}
```

I have to merge all the lists `lst` from the `ListContainer` objects from a `Map` map.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
   List<AClass> alltheObjectsAClass = map.values().stream(). // continue....    
}
```

Any idea how, using Java 8 stream API?

Comment: Can you provide an example what you mean with merging? Say your map is `{a: [1,2], b[3,4]}`, do you want to chain them, like `[1,2,3,4]`, or make a list of lists, `[[1,2],[3,4]]`, or zip them `[[1,3],[2,4]]`? Also, you are aware that a Map has no order, are you?

Comment: @tobias_k I want the result to be `[1,2,3,4]`, unsorted!

Comment: If `ListContainer` only wraps a `List<T>` then you can replace `Map<Key, ListContainer>` with `Map<Key, List<T>>`

Answer (score 212, accepted):

I think [`flatMap()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#flatMap-java.util.function.Function-) is what you're looking for.

For example:

```
 List<AClass> allTheObjects = map.values()
         .stream()
         .flatMap(listContainer -> listContainer.lst.stream())
         .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Comment: ? Why were the comments deleted that explained why  `.flatMap(Collection::stream)` is not possible here?

Comment: @Puce good question, however it's kind-of possible: if `ListContainer` is encapsulated (i.e. has a getter for `lst`), you can decompose `.flatMap(->)` into `.map(ListContainer::getLst)` `.flatMap(Collection::stream)`

Comment: @TWiStErRob Yes, that is what I wrote in my original comment. Why was it deleted?

Comment: @Puce a note in your answer explaining why `.flatMap(Collection::stream)` is no possible would be better, I think. Should be more permanent.

Comment: how we can make `flatMap(listContainer -> listContainer.lst.stream())` null pointer safe? In case if  `listContainer.lst` equals `null`. Ok I got it. Sorry for that - we can do simple `.filter(listContainer -> listContainer.lst != null)` before flatMap

Comment: @Alex yes, this is one way resp. `.map(listContainer -> listContainer.lst).filter(Objects::nonNull).flatMap(Collection::stream)`

Answer (score 75):

Alternative: Stream.concat()

```
Stream.concat(map.values().stream(), listContainer.lst.stream())
                             .collect(Collectors.toList()
```

Comment: plus 1 even though it does not answer the question, it answers the title of the question

Answer (score 7):

Already answered above, but here's another approach you could take. I can't find the original post I adapted this from, but here's the code for the sake of your question. As noted above, the flatMap() function is what you'd be looking to utilize with Java 8. You can throw it in a utility class and just call "RandomUtils.combine(list1, list2, ...);" and you'd get a single List with all values. Just be careful with the wildcard - you could change this if you want a less generic method. You can also modify it for Sets - you just have to take care when using flatMap() on Sets to avoid data loss from equals/hashCode methods due to the nature of the Set interface.

Edit - If you use a generic method like this for the Set interface, and you happen to use Lombok, make sure you understand how Lombok handles equals/hashCode generation.

```
  /**
    * Combines multiple lists into a single list containing all elements of
    * every list.
    * 
    * @param <T> - The type of the lists.
    * @param lists - The group of List implementations to combine
    * @return a single List<?> containing all elements of the passed in lists.
    */
   public static <T> List<?> combine(final List<?>... lists) {
      return Stream.of(lists).flatMap(List::stream).collect(Collectors.toList());
   }
```

Answer (score 3):

To merge several lists or other types of collections into a single one you can use this approach:

```java
Stream.of(list1.stream(), list2.stream(), someSet.stream(), otherCollection.stream())
    .flatMap(Function.identity())
    .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Answer (score 2):

In Java 8 we can use stream List1.stream().collect(Collectors.toList()).addAll(List2); Another option List1.addAll(List2)