# Query on parent and Children at same time with Morphia

Tags: java, mongodb, morphia

Suppose we have two objects:

```
class Server {
    ...
    String location;
    List<Status> statusList;
    ...
}

class Status {
    ...
    int code;
    ...
}
```

How can I get list of Status for all servers with same location. For example if `code == 1` and `location == "Beijing"`?

If I want to use createQuery(Server.class) and then .filter(), then output can not be list of Status!

Answer (score 0):

Shouldn't the following work for this?

```
List<Server> oops = createQuery(Server.class).find("location","Beijing").find("statusList.code", 1).asList();
```

Comment: I need `List<Status>` but here is `List<Server>`

Comment: You could do this in another step like this one here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23112874/java-8-merge-lists-with-stream-api

Answer (score 0):

Morphia doesnt support returning different types like that.  It will return you the type specified when you create the query.  You might be able to fake it out by creating the query with Status and the collection for Server and projecting only the Status field. You'll need to disable validation though.