# How to convert multiple list into single list using Java streams?

Tags: java, java-stream

I have an class `A` with multiple `List` members.

```
class A {
    List<X> xList;
    List<Y> yList;
    List<Z> zList;
    
    // getters and setters
}

class X {
     String desc;
     String xtype;
    
     // getters and setters    
}

class Y {   
    String name;
    String ytype;
    
    //getters and setters
}

class Z {
    String description;
    String ztype;
    
    // getters and setters    
}
```

And a class `B` with just 2 attributes:

```
class B {
    String name;
    String type;     
}
```

I need to iterate through the various lists in class `A` and create class `B` object and add to a list like this:

```
public void convertList(A a) {  
   List<B> b = new ArrayList<>();
    
    if (!a.getXList().isEmpty()) {
      for (final X x : a.getXList()) {
           b.add(new B(x.getDesc(), x.getXType()));
      }
    }
    
    if (!a.getYList().isEmpty()) {
      for (final Y y : a.getYList()) {
           b.add(new B(y.getName(), y.getYType()));
      }
    }
    
    if (!a.getZList().isEmpty()) {
      for (final Z z : a.getZList()) {
           b.add(new B(z.getDescription(), z.getZType()));
      }
    }    
}
```

As the if and for loops are repeated here.

How can I achieve this using Java streams?

Note: There is no relation between the classes `X`, `Y` and `Z` and there is no common interface.

Comment: have you tried using FlatMap, if not have a look here.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23112874/java-8-merge-lists-with-stream-api

Comment: Does X,Y and Z extend the same base class or implement the same interface containing both getName and getType?

Comment: Address the question properly because you are having multiple lists but passing ```x,z,y ``` as a type but expecting a list of  ```B```.

Comment: @JoakimDanielson Updated the question. There is no base class or interface. The attributes are all different in those classes. I need to convert to Class B based on the getters of each class.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Since your `X`, `Y` and `Z` types don't have a common super-type, you have to convert them into some common type, such as `Map.Entry<String,String>`.

You can create a `Stream` of all pairs of names and types, and then map it to instances of `B`:

```
List<B> b =
    Stream.of(
        a.getXList().stream().map(x -> new SimpleEntry<>(x.getDesc(),x.getXType())),
        a.getYList().stream().map(y -> new SimpleEntry<>(y.getName(),y.getYType())),
        a.getZList().stream().map(z -> new SimpleEntry<>(z.getDescription(),z.getZType())))
          .flatMap(Function.identity())
          .map(e -> new B(e.getKey(), e.getValue()))
          .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Or directly generate `B` instances:

```
List<B> b =
    Stream.of(
        a.getXList().stream().map(x -> new B(x.getDesc(),x.getXType())),
        a.getYList().stream().map(y -> new B(y.getName(),y.getYType())),
        a.getZList().stream().map(z -> new B(z.getDescription(),z.getZType())))
          .flatMap(Function.identity())
          .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Comment: What would be the point of generating a SimpleEntry and then mapping it to B?

Answer (score 13):

You can use `Stream.concat()` like following

```
public List<B> convertList (A a) {
    return Stream.concat(Stream.concat(a.getXList().stream().map(x -> new B(x.getDesc(), x.getXType()))
            , a.getYList().stream().map(y -> new B(y.getName(), y.getYType())))
            , a.getZList().stream().map(z -> new B(z.getDescription(), z.getZType()))).collect(Collectors.toList());
}
```

Comment: @Hadi J I'm getting Bad return type in lambda expression. B cannot be converted to R

Comment: I have run this version in my local machine it works for me

Comment: My bad I had close braces at the wrong place. This looks good. Thanks!

Answer (score 6):

Since you don't have a common interface, you would have to use a `forEach` method to iterate through each list.

```
a.getXList().forEach(i -> b.add(new B(i.getDesc(), i.getXType())));
a.getYList().forEach(i -> b.add(new B(i.getName(), i.getYType())));
a.getZList().forEach(i -> b.add(new B(i.getDescription(), i.getZType())));
```

Comment: OP needs `java streams` answer you can mention in your answer for non-stream answer.

Answer (score 4):

You are using the different property for X, Y, Z class, and not having common interface, you can add one by one in the list.

```
b.addAll(a.getXList().stream().map(x ->new B(x.getDesc(), x.getXType())).collect(Collectors.toList()));
b.addAll(a.getYList().stream().map(y ->new B(y.getName(), y.getYType())).collect(Collectors.toList()));
b.addAll(a.getZList().stream().map(z ->new B(z.getDescription(), z.getZType())).collect(Collectors.toList()));
```